# Alternative to rowid in sqlite in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

By rowid i mean the implicit column in all sqlite tables which stores the row number.

I can use rowid in sqlite using

```
 c.execute('SELECT rowid,* FROM table_name):
```

What can i do to use the `rowid` value in sqlalchemy?

Comment: What RDBMs are you using with sqlalchemy?

Comment: im using sqlite, im using the same ".db" file i was using when i was using sqlite3.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help some one, what I found out is that you need to create the table without the `rowid` column, and then you can simply map the field rowid to a column in the object.

*if you call `Base.Metadata.create_all(engine)` the column `rowid` will be created in the table, this will disable sqlite `rowid` generation.
* didn't check what happen if the primary key is Integer, I think this will override the `rowid`.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import *

# create the table
metadata = MetaData()
user = Table('users', metadata,
             Column('name', String, primary_key=True),
             Column('fullname', String))

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///example.db')
metadata.create_all(engine)

# create the user object
Base = declarative_base()
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    fullname = Column(String)
    rowid = Column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User: name='%s', fullname='%s'" % (self.name, self.fullname)

# insert users
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
u1 = User(name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones')
u2 = User(name='fred', fullname='Fred Jones')
u3 = User(name='ted', fullname='Ted Jones', rowid=99)

session = Session()
session.add_all([u1, u2, u3])
session.commit()

# read users
users = session.query(User).all()
for user in users:
    print(user, ", rowid=", user.rowid)
```

The output:

```
User: name='ed', fullname='Ed Jones' , rowid= 1   
User: name='fred',fullname='Fred Jones' , rowid= 2   
User: name='ted', fullname='Ted Jones' , rowid= 99
```